# What does .modal('dispose') do? Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

According to the documentation the [`.modal('dispose')`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modaldispose), destroys the modal.

> ```
> .modal('dispose')
> ```
>
> Destroys an element’s modal.

But when I create an `eventListener` using

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
    // Destroy modal
    $('#myModal').modal('dispose');
});
```

The modal is still part of the document. The documentation confuses me, is this method not used to remove the modal from the document? What is the purpose of this method?

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show');

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  console.log('Destroy modal');
  $('#myModal').modal('dispose');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It destroys the jQuery instance of the Bootstrap's Modal component. It doesn't remove the Modal markup from the DOM.

Comment: This part of the awnser should really be added to the documentation `It destroys the jQuery instance of the Bootstrap's Modal component`

Comment: What's point of destroying the jQuery instance? All the methods still work on the same instance/element, e.g. `$('#myModal').modal('toggle')` still works even after `$('#myModal').modal('dispose');`.