# Bootstrap 4 destroy a modal when it is closed

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm looking for a solution on my problem. I'm using bootstrap4 on laravel project. I have a modal that has a button which close it self and open a new modal. This is the code:

```
$("#newAddressBtn").on('click', function () {
    $('#modalAddressees').modal('hide')
    $('#modalAddressees').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        // Load up a new modal...
        $('#modalNewAddress').modal('show');
    })
});
```

Inside this new modal (modalNewAddress) I have a button that dismiss it. But when I dismiss it, I would to destroy it self because if I need to re-open it again, I would to start with empty data inside (such us the first show).

I wrote this code but nothing happens:

```
[....]
.on('core.form.valid', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route("addresses.store") }}",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')},
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: $("#addressForm").serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            destroyModal("#modalNewAddress");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('error ' + data);
        }
    });

});
[....]
function destroyModal(modal){
    $(modal).modal('dispose');
}
```

This is the code of the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalNewAddress">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">New Address</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" id="addressForm" action="{{ route("addresses.store") }}" class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="float-right">
                    <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </span>
                <input type="hidden" name="ajax">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer bg-whitesmoke br">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve the problem? Could you please help me?

Comment: can you add the modal? If modal have form then you could clear form elements like, `$('#myForm')[0].reset();` or you could manually reset each field.

Comment: I added the code of modal with only one form-group. Imagine to have more of that.

Comment: I tried your code inside  $().ready(function () {}); but it doesn't work

Comment: Inside your `destroyModal()` function, try this code, `$('#addressForm')[0].reset();`

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626434/what-does-modaldispose-do-bootstrap-4) answer, `modal('dispose');` only destroys the jQuery instance of the Bootstrap's Modal component not the markup. So you have to reset the form.

Comment: Ok thanks, it worked. But only for fields value. How can I reset all things of the form such us it first launch? (for example after reopen, I can see the formvalidation value of the last time)

Comment: use a class name in validation error message and clear elements with that class after resetting the form fields. eg : `$('.error_messages').html('');`

Answer (score -1):

You're not supposed to destroy the modal but recycle it.

The usage pattern would be as follows:

1. the modal does not contain data, but data fields you can reach with jQuery, such as:

   ```
   <div id="adress-nome"></div>
   <!-- more fields ... -->
   ```
2. before you open the modal, you populate it with a function, such as:

   ```
   function updateModal(data)
   {
     $("#address-nome").val(data.nome);
     // more data ...
   }

   function openModal(data)
   {
     updateModal(data);
     $("#address-modal").modal("show");
   }
   ```
3. when you're done with the modal, just hide it
4. when you re-open it, it will contain the new data

Comment: I don't need to have data when I open it, but I need it will be with empty fields...